git p4 clone get stuck at the p4 -G files step
I'm trying to perform git p4 clone but it doesn't seem to work
git p4 clone -v //path/to/my/depot/branches/mybranch
Importing from //path/to/my/depot/branches/mybranch into my-branch
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/<user>/Projects/my-branch/.git/
Reading pipe: git config --bool git-p4.useclientspec
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.user
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.password
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.port
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.host
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.client
Reading pipe: git config --int git-p4.retries
Reading pipe: git config --int git-p4.retries
Opening pipe: p4 -r 3 -G login -s
Opening pipe: p4 -r 3 -G login -s
Doing initial import of //path/to/my/depot/branches/mybranch from revision #head into refs/remotes/p4/master
Opening pipe: p4 -r 3 -G files //path/to/my/depot/branches/mybranch...#head
.... 
// gets stuck here forever

Perforce client error:
    TCP receive failed.
    read: socket: Operation timed out
p4 returned an error: TCP receive failed.
read: socket: Operation timed out

Before this, I performed
p4 login
Enter password: 
User <User> logged in.

my ~/.zshrc file has entries like
export P4USER=<username>
export P4PASS=<password>
export P4PORT=perforce:1666
export P4HOST=MBP-<username>.local

executing the p4 command standalone without the -G flag works
p4 files //path/to/my/depot/branches/mybranch...#head

However with the -G flag the command doesn't work.
I'm using MacOS 15.1 with Python 3.9.6

If you run p4 -G files //path/to/my/depot/branches/mybranch...#head (note the -G goes in between p4 and files, not after files), you get the same "Operation timed out"?  Or a different error?

I ask because it's hard for me to believe that -G would on its own cause a network error (its function is to reformat the output the client receives, not to change anything about the network connection) -- I'd be more inclined to suspect that git-p4.port is the wrong value and you get the error because there's no server running on the port that it's trying to connect to.  But if -G is in fact the crucial variable then it's a bug in the p4 client app and you should report it to Perforce support.

yes, it hard for me to believe too but still when I try
p4 files //path/to/my/depot/branches/mybranch...#head works
p4 -G files //path/to/my/depot/branches/mybranch...#head doesn't work

I just wish this line could be configured
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-p4.py#L864

Simply removing -G would completely break the script, I imagine, since it'll be dependent on the formatting that -G provides.  Could you edit your question to include the output you get when you run the command at the terminal with -G?  And maybe also p4 -V since that's relevant to the bug if there is one?
